# Improve ng-repeat performance besides 'track by' and single binding '::'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

In the hunt for improving Angular performance, the main chunk of my digest cycle (1s) is taken by ngRepeatAction (up to 300ms), which is unacceptable. I've been looking for ways to improve performance, these are my findings and things done:

- Use `track by $index` (or `item.id`) , everywhere
- Use bind once `::`, where possible

Example: `ng-repeat="event in ::events track by $index`

Other things I've found include: (but are not applicable in my app context)

- `limitTo : limit`
- filters, to avoid because they're run twice per digest.

Note: this is not concerning long lists (max 50 items), just A LOT of lists.

Are there any other ways to improve `ng-repeat`'s performance, things I could look into? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Probably you could do virtual scroll. But there are a few limitations. Check https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat (or) https://github.com/stackfull/angular-virtual-scroll

Comment: Probably not. As I said, my lists are short. Nowhere to scroll. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Oh. I mis read your question. If your lists are small, do you really need to bother beyond `track by $index`? :P

Comment: I feel like I should, as its watchAction is 300ms. Which is huge. I'm afraid there isn't really much more I can do. Guess I'll be looking into ngReact!

Comment: define "A LOT of lists" and how you measure the 300ms and on which device.

Comment: Hard to count and depends on the page, about 20. Measuring on safari ipad with safaris timeline recording connected to mac. No problem on desktop, ofcourse.